# Wix Setup Project breaks unrelated Migrations update-database call

Tags: entity-framework, wix, entity-framework-migrations

Running `update-database` from the Package Manager Console on an ASP.NET MVC Web Application fails after I add an unrelated Wix setup project to my solution.

Why is `update-database` accessing this unrelated project? Why does the presence of the wix project trigger a load of an assembly that cannot be found? How do I fix this?

This happens in a larger solution with web, desktop, installer projects, but after considerable head-scratching I reproduced this in isolation:

- Setup a new stock-standard VS solution with an ASP.NET MVC Web Application, Entity Framework, enable migrations, add WebMatrix components, setup Role provider.
- Add Configuration.Seed() method to call out to `WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(..)` and `System.Web.Security.Roles`.

Run `update-database`. It will work fine.  Now add a Wix setup project (no need to configure) and it will fail at/before executing `Seed()` with

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So, it seems having a Wix project in my solution triggers the load of an additional (not found) assembly when trying to call WebSecurity / WebMatrix methods through update-database from the Package Manager Console.

Workaround: Unload the Wix setup project and restart Visual Studio. There is no need to remove the project entirely.

Adding the missing dll to the GAC or a reference to the machine.config does not help. The dll is found but loading it errors out with

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)
```

Using `FUSLOGVW.exe` to log assembly load events didn't help. It basically shows that `update-database` can't find the v15.1 dll because it's not in the GAC and there is no app/host/system config file pointing at it.

Running the seed method from the running web application (enable automatic migration) works fine.

And yes, I am setting PMC "default project" to the web application, ie, point `update-database` at the web application.

Details:

- Visual Studio Professional 2017 on Win 10 Pro fully patched.
- Recently upgraded VS from 2015. No such problem under 2015.
- Wix Toolset 3.11.0.1528
- Package Manager Console 4.1.0.2427
- System.Web.Mvc 5.2.3.0
- Entity Framework 6.1.3
- WebMatrix.Data.dll 3.0.0.0
- WebMatrix.WebData.dll 3.0.0.0
- Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll v15.1.0.0 lives in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\ and Visual studio has a redirect to it in its app.config.

Snippets:

Configuration.cs:

```
class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContextHere>
{
    public Configuration() { AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false; }

    protected override void Seed(Stash context)
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfiles", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);    
        if(!Roles.RoleExists("G1")) Roles.CreateRole("G1");
    }
}
`
```

web.config:

```
`
<configuration>  
  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Comment: This discussion looks related. 
 A few suggestions, but no solution that works for everyone. 
 Did you find a fix for this?
 https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25424/error-running-entity-framework-6-code-first-migrat.html

Comment: TWilly: We haven't found a fix. Current workaround: We unload the installer projects & restart VS before update-database. Painful, but not enough time to investigate further right now. Will have a look at your link when I get a chance. Thanks. T.